# Fabric js How to set percentage object's position

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using Fabric.js and i changing canvas size dynamically, so i need scale all canvas objects with appropriate objects indents (in percent depending on canvas size) top and left. How i can set top and left objects position in percent?

like in css:

top: 32%
left: 10%

```js
// set canvas size dynamically by resize event
this.canvas.setWidth(size.width);
this.canvas.setHeight(size.height);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should have two values in order to calculate resize ratio.

initialCanvasWidth and finalCanvasWidth.

By assuming that you have initialCanvasWidth value in page load. You can calculate resize ratio on every resize by a function like this:

```
          window.onresize = utility.debounce(() => {
            const finalCanvasWidth = canvasWrapper.clientWidth
            const resizeRatio = (finalCanvasWidth / initialCanvasWidth).toFixed(3)

            setCanvasSizeAndPosition()
            scaleObjectsOnCanvas(resizeRatio)
        }, 250)
```

By wrapping your canvas with a div and by using its new width after resize, you can set your new canvas width and height (in setCanvasSizeAndPosition function)

```
    this.canvas.setWidth(newWidth).setHeight(newHeight)
```

I think you will also need to store your aspect ratio of your canvas at the beginning in order to calculate newHeight value

After setting your new canvas size, you can continue with scaling and positioning objects on canvas (scaleObjectsOnCanvas function)

```
    scaleObjectsOnCanvas(resizeRatio) {
        const objects = canvas.getObjects()
        for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            objects[i].left = objects[i].left * resizeRatio
            objects[i].top = objects[i].top * resizeRatio
            objects[i].scaleX = objects[i].scaleX * resizeRatio
            objects[i].scaleY = objects[i].scaleY * resizeRatio
        }
        this.canvas.renderAll()
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Here's a [real world working example](https://www.ciceksepeti.com/kisiye-ozel-tasarim-duvar-saati-hf10550) of responsive canvas/fabric.js usage

Comment: So... initially, I thought of this idea... used my own code... had problems with element positions, yet not resizing oddly enough... came to SO and found this... checked it against mine... still had issues... the end solution: draw a rectangle as big as the canvas and center it... select everything... resize the canvas... scale the rectangle (and naturally the contents will be scaled to size)... center the rectangle (and naturally the contents will be placed in their proper positions)... delete the rectangle... render all.